# How to use non printable characters in swift string variable?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to use non printable characters in a `String` constant, but Xcode shows error in my swift file as **"Unprintable ASCII character found in source file"**

My Simple code is below

```
let unprintableCharInString = "12345"
```

You could see the non printable characters at prefix and suffix of above string value, If you just copy paste my above code in Sublime text or some other text editor which supports to show Unprintable characters.

But if you paste the above code in Xcode swift file, you will see the compiler error **"Unprintable ASCII character found in source file"**.

And if I use the same string in Objective C as like below, there is no error.

```
NSString *unprintableCharInString = @"12345";
```

So how to use non printable characters in Swift string variable directly as like  above Objective C code?

**Note:
As the body text box trims those non printable chars while saving my question, you can't see those chars if you copy paste the code from here. Instead of that try to copy the above code by editing my question. So you can get those chars in Body text box during edit.**

Screenshot from Sublime Text editor:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh.. It seems After submit my question those chars are removed. I guess.

Comment: If you edit my question and copy(from editing text box) past the above codes in external text editor like sublime, you could see those non printable chars.

Comment: What is the point of including unprintable chars in your source code? Why don't you _encode_ them to ASCII if it's crucial for you?

Comment: @Alladinian i'm writing unit test cases. So I want to check the prefix and suffix of my string contains such unprintable characters. Also may I know how to encode it to ASCII programmatically without including that string in source code?

Comment: Well in that case you could include unprintable unicode chars in your strings with something like this: `let unprintableCharInString = "\u{02}123\u{1A}"`. As for an api, you could use `let char = Unicode.Scalar(0x02).escaped(asASCII: true)` for example...

Comment: Thank you @Alladinian. Your solution works in my case.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the @Alladinian's suggestion in Comment above,

Answer is: We need to add the unprintable ASCII characters manually in source code while declaring string value.

Example:

```
let unprintableCharInString = "\u{02}123\u{1A}"
```

Here `\u{02}` is Hex value of "START OF TEXT (STX)" and `\u{1A}` is Hex value of "SUBSTITUTE (SUB)"

Thanks @Alladinian!

Answer (score 2):

To display space characters you can use XCode `Editor > Show Invisibles`. But I'm not really sure will it help in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to display the unprintable characters in Xcode. I just want to avoid the compiler error as like Objective C code.